# How to upload and size a profile picture for a site?

Tags: vb.net, image-processing, image-manipulation, picturebox

I have a site that has a profile page and I would like to allow the users to upload an image for the profile picture.  I forsee a problem if the user select an image that is larger than what I am allowing for the site.  Is their a good refrence or example how to accomplish this?

The site is developed in Visual Studio 2008 with VB.NET 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

The following site contains a good example of how to do this - [Hybrid ASP.NET File Upload and Resize Sample (VB.NET)](http://offbeatmammal.com/upload_resize.aspx).

Comment: I just noticed that you've provided a *PictureBox* tag but at the beginning you refer to a site ... Does that mean you're using a Rich Client or ASP.NET?  If it is the former, the image resizing code should still be of value.

Answer (score 1):

If the image is the right shape but just too large you can use the method that [Bermo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632611/how-to-upload-and-size-a-profile-picture-for-a-site/2644951#2644951) talks about.

However if you'd like to choose the most interesting part of the image you can use the technique that [Reddit](http://reddit.com) uses for it's thumbnails.

See [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/7sudx/why_does_the_reddit_thumbnail_for_amazoncom_looks/) for some info and the source code (Python) is [here](http://code.reddit.com/browser/r2/r2/lib/scraper.py). Basically it splits the image up into sections and works out which ones are the most interesting by using the `entropy` value.